# trainControl in caret package

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, training-data

In caret package, there is a thing called trainControl that allow us to perform variety of cross validation. To perform 10-fold cross-validation, one would use

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method= "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 10)
fitJ48_10_fold <- train(x = x, y =y, method = "J48", trControl= fitControl)
```

while for training set, it is

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method= "none")
fitJ48train <- train(x = x, y =y, method = "J48", trControl= fitControl)
```

However, confusion matrix of these model show the same for both 10-fold and training.

```
Activity <- predict(fitJ48_10_fold, newdata = Train)
confusionMatrix(Activity, Train$Activity)

Activity <- predict(fitJ48train, newdata = Train)
confusionMatrix(Activity, Train$Activity)
```

I used the weka classifier GUI and indeed the performance of J48 from 10-fold cross validation is lower than that of training set. Am I wrong to suspect that the trainControl from caret isn't working or I pass this in a wrong way?

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for prompt reply and R community. Data can be accessible at the following link. https://github.com/Rnewbie/LikitMorganFP/blob/master/cdetermanrequest.csv

 [link](https://github.com/Rnewbie/LikitMorganFP/blob/master/cdetermanrequest.csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I wrong to suspect that the trainControl from caret isn't working or I pass this in a wrong way?

A little. For `J48`, there is a tuning parameter but the default grid only fits a single value `C = 0.25`. The final model will be the same no matter what value of `method` that you use in `trainControl` so the confusion matrices will always be the same.

Max